# Google Sheets regexextract nth date string

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Here's what I have:

=regexextract(A1,"(\d+/\d+/\d+){3}")

This will return the first date string:

REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(\d+/\d+/\d+){1}")

But this returns N/A:

REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(\d+/\d+/\d+){3}")

Goal: regexextract regex to return nth date string matching the format (1 or 2 digit)/(1 or 2 digit)/(2 digit). There are multiple char(10) breaks in the string as depicted in example string:

A 1234
Text Text
123-456-7890
Fri 1/14/22
9:00 AM, 12:00 PM
Tue 10/18/22
10:30 AM, 4:30 PM, A 2506
Text Text
123-456-7890
Tue 11/1/22
9:00 AM, 4:30 PM
Wed 1/19/22
9:00 AM, 4:30 PM

So for this example I'd like to be able to return 1/14/22 or 10/18/22 or 11/1/22 or 1/19/22 by selecting nth value i.e. 1,2,3, or 4. If the 3-letter abbreviated day of the week e.g. "Wed" could also be returned as shown in the example ahead of the date result, that regex would be additionally helpful. Thank you for reading and in advance for any help. I am sorry but it appears the char(10) breaks are not being shown after I posted the question - I am not sure how to fix that. There is a char(10) break immediately preceding the abbreviated weekday and after the sought date result, e.g. before and after "Fri 1/14/22".

Comment: Can you at least demonstrate your understanding of matching a digit using regex ?

Comment: Yes of course, apologies. I forgot to include what I have: =regexextract(A1,"(\d+/\d+/\d+){3}") . I've also added it in an edit to the original question.

Comment: Your post did not hold formatting of the example string. So we don't know where the CHAR(10) breaks are.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Erik. I had mentioned I do not know how to hold formatting. All date strings I am trying to extract have the format RE char(10) inclusion as, e.g.: =char(10)&"Tue 10/18/22"&char(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, replacing the number in the bracket returns the nth match of the date string:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:.*?(\d+/\d+/\d+)){3}")
```

[image: finished code]

Now I'll worry about adding the abbreviated day. Thanks to all for your contributions.

...and with the abbreviated day:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:.*?([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d+/\d+/\d+)){3}")
```

[image: code with abbreviated day]

Thanks again to all who contributed responses in helping to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the text you have provided, and if you have 4 dates within the text, with or without car(10), try

```
=regexextract(A1,"([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}).*([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}).*([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}).*([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2})")
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, thank you very much for your response. I see the first string sought is returned, however, how do I return the nth string? E.g. if I want the third for the presented case, the result would be: Tue 11/1/22